# Was the end-of-life counseling provision kept in Obamacare?

Tags: united-states, law, healthcare

In the initial version of Obamacare, there was a provision in which if someone wanted to have a voluntary counseling session with a doctor about end-of-life care, discussing things like advanced directives, then Medicare would pay for that session.  Somehow that was twisted by opponents of the bill into a claim that there were Death Panels, government boards that would choose whether you live or die.

My question is, was an end-of-life counseling provision kept in the final version of the bill?  Some sources I've seen say that Democrats took it out of the bill, just to try to stop the lie about Death Panels.  But other sources I've seen said that a weakened version of it was kept, in which rather than a separate counseling session, patients had the option of talking to the doctor about end-of-life care as part of their yearly Medicare checkup.

Can anyone clarify which of these is right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: It's interesting that if user18 posted a question that baselessly accused someone of lying for partisan reasons, it'd have been downvoted to oblibion. This question, which doesn't even attempt to hide its bias, gets +3.

Comment: For the record, the Death Panels idea was mostly due to the simple logical conclusion that Obamacare will lead to health care rationing. To quote that uber-hard-right-wing consevative, H. Dean: "IPAB is... essentially a health-care rationing body."

Comment: Oh, here's another conservartive thinker, along same lines: http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2013/02/22/lying-worm-becks-reaction-to-krugmans-death-panel-remarks/

Comment: @DVK I didn't speculate about why they lied, I just mentioned the fact that they lied, which is pretty firmly established.  It was, after all, Politifact's Lie of the Year: www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2009/dec/18/politifact-lie-year-death-panels/

Comment: just because politifact doesn't bother looking at, y'know, facts (see quotes above) isn't my problem. The point is that whether counceling was or wasn't in the final version has nothing to do with your clearly biased wording, yet you get upvotes since it makes Rs look bad. Any question where the wording - no matter how relevant - makes Dems look bad gets a wave of downvotes, for "bias"

Comment: @DVK I don't see how my wording is biased at all.  It's pretty well-established by mainstream, neutral sources that Republicans lied about Death Panels.  Whether the IPAB amounts to rationing is a seperate question than "death panels".  (The IPAB isn't allowed to deny people care or treatments, for instance, so it's hard to even call it a rationing board.). But in any case, Howard Dean isn't really an expert on the healthcare law, and neither is Glenn Beck, especially when Beck is quoting Krugman making a joke about Death Panels.

Comment: I think Politifact did a pretty thorough investigation of the facts, and its assessment is accepted by mainstream sources.

Comment: I read their assessment. NOWHERE in it they bothered revealing that Death Panels was about rationing and NOT about end of life counseling. If you bother reading my 2 links above, you'll see that what Palin said was not being openly agreed to by pretty high level liberals (Dean and Krugman). Or for that matter Obama himself, though in less direct form.

Comment: The end-of-life counseling provision is what Palin and others cited when talking about Death Panels.  As I said, the IPAB is not able to deny people care or decide not to pay for treatments.  Krugman was NOT admitting that the healthcare law had Death Panels.  He said Death Panels as a joke, and what he was actually talking about was something that wasn't In the healthcare law, but rather something he was proposing we do in the future.  He was proposing that we limit how much money Medicare spends on end-of-life care.  But you can ask a new question if you want to discuss this further.

Comment: I'll take Dean's word on IPAB over yours. And if you bother reading Politifact's quote of what Palin said, she was NOT talking about end of life counceling. (among other things, because counceling wasn't planned on being done by the panels but by the health care provider, DUH)

Comment: The two people most prominently associated with the term death panels, Sarah Palin and Betsy McCaughey, both cited the section 1233 provision, which was about end-of-life counseling with a doctor but was portrayed as death panels.  See here: abcnews.go.com/blogs/politics/2009/08/palin-paints-picture-of-obama-death-panel-giving-thumbs-down-to-trig/. Again, if you want to discuss IPAB and death panels further, we should do it in a seperate question.

Comment: By the way, here is proof that the IPAB cannot engage in rationing: any proposal that the IPAB makes "shall not include any recommendation to ration health care, raise revenues or Medicare beneficiary premiums under section 1395i–2, 1395i–2a, or 1395r of this title, increase Medicare beneficiary cost-sharing (including deductibles, coinsurance, and copayments), or otherwise restrict benefits or modify eligibility criteria."  www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/1395kkk

Comment: can not doesn't mean it won't later. Lefties never tried to hide that Obamacare is the minimum of what they can get away with now, and not the end goal. Again, see 2 links above.

Comment: Well, all I mentioned in my question is the fact that Republicans lied about Dwath Panels being in the healthcare law.  If you want to talk about the possibility of future liberal policies denying people care, you can create a separate question about that.

Comment: The design of Obamacare logically leads to death panels. That's a fact, not a lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the provision was omitted. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_panel):

> Due to public concern, the provision to pay physicians for providing voluntary counseling was removed from the Senate bill and was not included in the law that was enacted, the 2010 Patient Protection and Affordable Care Act.

Apparently there was regulation that would allow medicare to cover end-of-life consultations during annual check-ups, but those regulations lasted only a few days:

> In late December 2010, it was reported that a new Medicare regulation had been approved that would pay for end-of-life care consultations during annual physical exams. The regulation was to be effective January 1, 2011,[13] but was deleted on January 4 for political reasons.

The [New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/05/health/policy/05health.html?_r=0&adxnnl=1&adxnnlx=1387504863-GQxd1HeDobaqxE21/ojdPA) to which wikipedia links suggests that it was removed to make the bill easier to defend from anticipated attacks by the Republican majority in the House of Representatives elected in 2010:

> While administration officials cited procedural reasons for changing the rule, it was clear that political concerns were also a factor. The renewed debate over advance care planning threatened to become a distraction to administration officials who were gearing up to defend the health law against attack by the new Republican majority in the House.

Comment: It looks like CMS is planning to reinstate the regulation: http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/medicare-proposes-to-pay-doctors-to-have-end-of-life-care-discussions/2015/07/08/1d7bb436-25a7-11e5-aae2-6c4f59b050aa_story.html Of course, they may change their mind at the last minute again if there's another uproar like last time.